# On Android : making a phonecall using a browser application

Tags: android, phone-call

On `Android` devices, does anyone has checked that if a user clicks on a link

```
<a href='wtai://wp/mc;5551231367' title='Call'>555.123.1367</a>
```

this would propose the user to make a call to this phone number ?

If not, do you know how is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link needs to be

```
<a href="tel:<number you want to have dialled"> Call </a>
```

so for the number you used:

```
<a href="tel:5551231367"> Call 555.123.1367 </a>
```