# is there a way to open call dial from html?

Tags: iphone, android, html, mobile-webkit

In Html
I'm looking for a kind of tag or attribute a little bit like :

> href="mailto:foo@bar.com"

but

```
href="phoneto:+11XXXXXXXX"
```

does it exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for the iPhone
The html/url format is:

```
href="tel:########"
```

in Objective-C code: 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:8005551212"]];`

Here is a link to the relevant [Apple Documentation on URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference.pdf).

Comment: @Christophe Debove: As walter already explained, the URL scheme is "tel".

Comment: yep I didn't see. walter can you edit your answer with coloration and style

Answer (score 1):

The format for Android is href="tel:xxxxxxxx"

see previous stackoverflow answer at : [On Android : making a phonecall using a browser application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022125/on-android-making-a-phonecall-using-a-browser-application)