# Launch a phonecall with windowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-8, phone-call

I add a page Support in my WindowsPhone Application.
I would like when the user click on Support to launch a phone call.
Do you know how is it possible, i don't find related documentation on it.

[UPDATE]
I try to add this and display in a texblock. doesn't work.
[On Android : making a phonecall using a browser application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022125/on-android-making-a-phonecall-using-a-browser-application)

[UPDATE]
I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025(v=vs.105).aspx and it works correctly enjoy :)

[Update]
It's a task action as send a mail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394025(v=vs.105).aspx this link is really good

Best regards,
Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a PhoneCallTask:

```
     PhoneCallTask callTask = new PhoneCallTask();
     callTask.PhoneNumber = "999999";
     callTask.DisplayName = "Support";
     callTask.Show();
```

Remember to enable ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER in your WMAppManifest.xml

Comment: I see, that you have already found the answer. As this post already is written I'll leave it so that maybe it will be helpful for somebody else.